# Back button Wont work

Tags: android, button, back, app-inventor

I have created an app using appinvintor. The problem is when i hit the back button on my android it closes the whole application i just want it to go to the previous step or page, how would i code that

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can't do that because right now we are given only one screen. But you can manipulate like [this](http://www.appinventorblocks.com/sample-apps#tarsier_attack).

Answer (score 0):

since beginning of 2012 there is the multiple screen feature in AI and now it is possible to catch the back button, see this example http://puravidaapps.com/backbutton.php
Taifun